# UIButton with transparent image background not drawing transparent

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibutton

I have run into a strange issue. I have a `UIButton` with `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

For it's background image, I am using a transparent image. The issue is that the transparency on the actual image doesn't seem to be correct. The odd thing is that it is in fact transparent, because the background shows correctly behind the button.

Below is an example of what the button looks like (left) and what the button should look like (right). I took a screenshot and overlaid the image on the background in Photoshop, and the background shows correctly inside the image, while in the actual button on the left it does not. Noticeably, the glow is more intense on the left UIButton vs. the actual image when inserted onto the background.

[image: UIButton issue]

Here's the image I am using to show that it does in fact have transparency:

[image: Image used]

Here's my code:

```
UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
nextButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[nextButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBackground.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self addSubview:nextButton];

I have used the exact same image elsewhere to draw with and had no issue with transparency.

**UPDATE:** Adding other transparent images similarly increases the intensity of the alpha. While they're transparent, they seem darker and therefore less transparent. Again, works perfect elsewhere.

**UPDATE 2:** Even worse, I just created a new project with the exact same image dragged from the other project, created a button and had no issues with the button displaying correctly. How incredibly annoying!

Comment: have you tried setting the image property and not the backgroundImage property? does it make any difference then?

Comment: See conversations below.

Comment: You probably just needed a clean build. You must have had an old image that was less or not transparent and changed it for a new one and it kept the reference to the old one. XCode seems clingy to deleted files for some reason.

Comment: If you ever change an image or file in your XCode project, its always a good idea to clean the project and it should update everything. Try cleaning your old project and see what happens.

Comment: based on update2: try: 1)xcode - clean project, 2)simulator - reset content and settings or delete the app 3)device - delete existing app

Comment: Did you solve this - i have a round image in a UIButton with transparent bounds, so it fits into a UIButton. When i scroll my tabel view a few times the images looses quality. When leave view an reload its perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to set the background color for it to be transparent. Also, try removing the stretchable call on the image.

Also, you should be setting the image, not the background image.

If none of that helps, then Apple may just be improperly rendering your image. Try creating a CALayer and set its contents to your image and see if that works properly.

Comment: You cannot stretch an image on a UIButton, so I have to set the background image, which should be fine. In any event, either one doesn't solve it.

Comment: Hmmm. I've never had this problem before. Why can't you just recreate the image at the proper size? Or just recreate it by scaling the image in code before you add it to your button. Try scaling it before you add it to your button and then add it to your button as the image, rather than background image.

Comment: Are you positive that the image is the same one you're using in photoshop? Have you tried dragging in the image from XCode into photoshop to make sure that the image you have added to your project is the exact same?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. The image above is a screenshot, with the image overlaid on the right side vs. the button with the exact same image on the left.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone can figure it out. My best guess is that apple can't render your image data properly for some reason, but I've never had an issue with transparencies before. You could always import it without transparencies and then edit that layer to lower its opacity.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is just plain wrong. Removing the stretchable image call will not give the desired results. Also, he is setting the background image correctly.

Comment: @megamer Yes. He is setting the background image correctly. But he should be setting the image as the UIButton's image property. How is this just plain wrong? This works for me.

Comment: No, he shouldn't, because then the button couldn't have a title, as UIButtons can only have either an image or a title. I have the exact same problem with one of my buttons.

Comment: His button doesn't have a title. Your problem is different. Did you even try setting the layer contents before downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

    nextButton.alpha=0.5f;

    [nextButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [nextButton setOpaque:NO];

    [nextButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBackground.png"] 
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Yes, setting the alpha, helps but doesn't solve the issue I am seeing with the image being drawn in the background at a seemingly higher intensity that it should be.

Comment: Again, it's not drawing with the same transparency as the actual image.